# Method throws Error instead of Returning null.Why?

Tags: c#

I sometimes get an **error**:

```
There is not a header with name UserName and namespace http://www.website.com/ in the message.
```

**Stacktrace**

> System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeaders.GetHeader[T](String name,
>   String ns, String[] actors)
>   Common.Utilities.WCF.WcfCallContext.TryGetHeader(String key)
>   Common.Utilities.WCF.WcfCallContext.get_UserName()

Here is the 2 Methods:

```
    private static string TryGetHeader( string key )
    {
        try
        {
            return GetHeader( key );
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static string GetHeader( string key )
    {
        var headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
        var value = headers.GetHeader<string>( key, "http://www.website.com/", "Project" );
        return value;
    }
}
```

So TryGetHeader(with try and catch) is calling GetHeader.
Obviously it breaks on the:

```
var value = headers.GetHeader<string>( key, "http://www.website.com/", "Project" );
```

Why is it then that `TryGetHeader` does not catch it as an error and not returning a `null`?
It is as if it breaks in `GetHeader` and stops instead of throwing back in error in `TryGetHeader`?

Comment: It seems like `FindHeader` and then (for values > -1) applying an indexing operation would prevent it from ever throwing an exception. You shouldn't write code that depends on particular exceptions being thrown (especially if you then catch all exceptions, not just the expected one)

Comment: Have you tried run code without debugging?

Comment: Is the error actually caught/unhandled by your own code, or is it only showing up in the debugger?

Comment: Medinoc raises a fair point. Is that actually breaking your code?

Answer (score 6):

If you call `TryGetHeader`, then that exception will be caught. I strongly suspect you are seeing a "first chance exception", or seeing the exception in the IDE / debugger. That is a phantom: the exception *is not really there* (or rather, it will get caught in normal execution). Try turning down the exception handling options in the IDE.